# c# sending mail pass string to body

Tags: c#, email, gmail-imap

I was following this: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

And after a few seconds realized that the body is a constant and I can't pass a string to it. Is there any fast way to change this code a bit and get what I need?

Comment: You can Use ' StringBuilder ' !!

Comment: Why the minuses? It seems logical to ask for help if you face difficulties and the original question didn't hold the answer that I was looking for. And as far as I understand the rules of commenting I shouldn't have asked this question in the comments of the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void PostMessage(string body,string subject)
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
            const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
        }
```

you can call it like this:

```
PostMessage("MAH BODY", "SUBJECT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You remove the `const` bit...

```
const string body = "Body";
```

turns into:

```
string body = bodyPassedIn; //where bodyPassedIn = is being passed into the method
```

You don't even need the variable at all:

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                     {
                         Subject = subject,
                         Body = bodyPassedIn // here!
                     })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```